# JavaScript - Global Variable not Changing

Tags: javascript, variables, global, reset

I am trying to store a file list in a global variable, so that individual files can be accessed by links. I have this HTML code:

```
<input type="file" id="input" multiple onchange="readFiles(this.files)">
```

Then in an external JavaScript file:

```
theFileList = null;

function test() {
    if (theFileList)
        alert(theFileList[0]);
    else
        alert("It is null!");
}

function readFiles(fileList) {
    if (fileList) {
        // I generate a new page in the "main" frame:
        var doc = parent.document.getElementById('main').contentWindow.document;
        theFileList = fileList;
        test(); // works fine (displays "[object File]").

        // opens html and head tags; writes head section (with stylesheet and external js; closes head and opens body:
        generateHeader(); 
        // create a button to check if global variable is null:
        doc.writeln("<button onclick=\"javascript:test();\">Click</button>");
        // closes body and html tags:
        generateFooter();

        doc.close();
    }
    else
        alert("Something went wrong");
}
```

As stated in the comment, when the files are first loaded, the test function displays the correct output.
However, when the generated button is clicked, the output is "It is null!".

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.
This is for an assignment and is quite urgent.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused about which code is executed where. If `doc` is not the same document in which the code you posted is loaded, then the button will execute `test` in a different context.

Comment: Are you sure that `        var doc = parent.document.getElementById('main').contentWindow.document;` is ok?

Comment: @FelixKling: I think this may be the case. How can I get around this?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the best solution here... you could try assigning `theFileList` as global variable to the other window: `doc.defaultView.theFileList = theFileList;`.

Comment: This didn't seem to work.

Comment: What does `generateHeader` do? How is there a `test` function defined in the frame at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just try to use `readFiles` before it was declared.

if you will change `function readFiles(fileList) {...}` to `window.readFiles = function (fileList) {...}` then `test` will say `[object File]`

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/GsCyM/)

I commeted line `parent.document.getElementById('main').contentWindow.document;` becouse I think it's not ok ( it's fire error =) ).

Comment: Yes, it also works for me. The problem is when I create a button and click it (then "It it null!" displays).

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/GsCyM/4 When the button is clicked, nothing happens.

Comment: @Mr_Bean: It seems to work for me in Chrome. Anyways, using `document.write` after the document was parsed will replace the whole document and browsers might reset the JavaScript environment as well. If you are working on the same document, you better use DOM manipulation.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks. So would I do this by accessing the body element and changing its inner HTML?

Comment: @Mr_Bean: That's one option, though using proper DOM manipulation/traversal gives you finer control over what you are modifying. Maybe this helps: http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-dom-intro/.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling; you have helped me greatly! One more thing: if I refresh the page, it reverts to the original inner HTML. Is there anyway to avoid this? I would guess there isn't.

Comment: @Mr_Bean: No, there isn't. You might be able to use local storage (http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) to preserve information between page loads and depending on their existence, decide which UI to build. But since it can only store strings, this might be too limited (e.g. you cannot store the selected files).

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks man. I am now appending strings to the body element, but when I try to add a table, it does weird things (such as adding </table> where I don't want it to). Any ideas?

Comment: @Mr_Bean: When you set `innerHTML`, the whole string is parsed and proper DOM is created. You cannot build partial HTML with it. Create the HTML string first and then assign, append it as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with your `var doc = parent.document.getElementById('main').contentWindow.document;` and not global variable. But the scopes you are using for your file.

Comment: Why is this the problem? What should it be changed to? If I use doc.writeln(...), it works fine.

Comment: That depends on how you call your JS